# removing specific charachter from value of a textfield everytime .val() is called on that textfield ( code should be inside jq plugin )

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry i couldn't think  of better title ! plus my english sucks

her is my first plugin (basically i repackaged some js code as a plugin  )

it adds a comma `,` separator to value every 3 digit ,  when someone types something inside textfield

```
  (function($){

      $.fn.num = function(userop){

            var options =  $.extend(  {seperator:','} , userop );

            $(this).keyup(function(e) {
                var num = $(this).val();
                var nStr = num + '';
                nStr = nStr.replace( /\,/g, "");
                var x = nStr.split( '.' );
                var x1 = x[0];
                var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
                var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
                while ( rgx.test(x1) ) {
                    x1 = x1.replace( rgx, '$1' + options.seperator + '$2' );
                }
                $(this).val( x1 + x2 );

            })
      }

  })(jQuery);

  $('.number_input').num();
```

but problem is if i put 123456 in my textfield

```
var n = $('.number_input').val();
console.log(n);
```

will return  `123,456`

which is fine but it suppose to be a numeric value and each time user has to extract commas manually
by running it trough something like

```
n = Number($.trim(n.replace(/\,/g,'')));
```

is there any way to add this line to my plugin so it gets executed when someone runs `.val()` on textfild ?

basically  i want to write comma remover once not every single time that i get each effected textfield  value

Comment: have you tried `parseInt()`?

Comment: @jackJoe 1 - yep , it wont work when there are multiple commas 2 - i want to write comma remover once not every single time that i get it's value

Comment: You could rewrite the `.val()` method, but this is a bad practice and can bring undesired behavior. You could write you own `val()` method (but change the name) and tell the user to use it, better practice but still bad. Lastly you could use a method inside you plugin that is being called like that : `$('.number_input').num('GET')`

Comment: Do you really need the commas in the first place? What is the goal of the plugin?

Comment: @TimSPQR improving readability ? never seen numbers separated by a comma every 3 digit ? just run `<?php echo number_format(123456); ?>`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i know what i ask is unusual , but rewriting .val will effect other textfields which may contain string with valid `,` ,  and  creating my own method would be plan B , could you explain a little more about the last one ?

Comment: @max something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/38ymH/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon it would ave been great if there was a `getval` event !!

Comment: @max What do you mean a `getval` event?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon  it's a joke ! a event that would be called when someone is trying to get value of a textfield

Comment: @max well, actually you *could* if you wanted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2My4F/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the default `.val()` method with the combination of the `.data()`, you'll be able the do what you want. Note that change `.val()` can have undesired effect (mostly when user try to override `.val()` aswell...)

Anyway, the first thing to do is give a data to every element that are active number. So in you init, add this code :

```
this.data('__numered', true);
```

Now we can detect if the element as a formatting.

Then here come the tricky part : overriding.

You'll have to save the old `.val()` method :

```
$.fn.__val = $.fn.val;
```

Then recreate `.val()` but check if its a numbered item :

```
$.fn.val = function(set){
    if(typeof set === 'undefined'){
        if(this.first().data('__numered'))
            return Number($.trim(this.first().__val().replace(/\,/g,'')));
        else
            return this.first().__val();

    }else
        return this.__val(set)
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Tw77J/1/

Answer (score 0):

## First of all

I think I'm suggesting a better way to do what you are asking, instead of directly answering.

If you use, my solution, your plugin gives the users the option of **getting what they want.** (*You cant predict what users need*)

## My Solution:

You can add this simple code:

```
if (userop == 'val') {
        return Number($.trim($(this).val().replace(/\,/g, '')));
}
```

So your plugin would become:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.num = function (userop) {

        if (userop == 'val') {
            return Number($.trim($(this).val().replace(/\,/g, '')));
        }

        var options = $.extend({
            seperator: ','
        }, userop);

        $(this).keyup(function (e) {
            var num = $(this).val();
            var nStr = num + '';
            nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, "");
            var x = nStr.split('.');
            var x1 = x[0];
            var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + options.seperator + '$2');
            }
            $(this).val(x1 + x2);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Remember, you are the creator of the plugin, and you **can** impose some rules for the developers using your plugin.

That said, ask your users to use `$('selector').num('val');` to get the value **without** commas, and `$('selector').val()`, if they want it **with** comma.

So to brush up:

1. Use `$('selector').num('val');` // with comma
2. Use `$('selector').val();` // without comma

Put that in readme file or any document file.

<kbd>**[Live demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/CmG3P/)**</kbd>

Also, don't forget me to add me as a contributor to the plugin, If my answer helped you ;)

Comment: thanx , it's the best next thing  after .val()

Comment: i know that ! i'm going to try karl answer first